# setMargins() is not working for tableRow to set Margins

Tags: android, tablerow

I have gone through different examples but i unable to find the exact answer for my requirement.  Below is my code. let me know where i went wrong.

```
     TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);
                    TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams params=
                              new TableLayout.LayoutParams
                              (TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    params.setMargins(20,20, 20, 5);
                    tableRow.setLayoutParams(params);

tableLayout.addView(tableRow, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Thanks..,

Comment: did U add tableRow to your tableLayout????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you make your call to `addView` you create new `LayoutParams` and according to the documentation about `addView`

> Adds a child view with the specified layout parameters.

I think that you should send params in your `addView` call instead of creating new `LayoutParams`